# Error on trying to put a comment into a macro even though it expands correctly

Tags: c++

I wanted to define a macro which will contain comment inside of it but I couldn't put it inside a macro.

More specifically, I wanted to turn this:

```
/* \deprecated "Car is deprecated" */ class [[deprecated("Car is deprecated")]] Car {}
```

into this:

```
DEPRECATED_CLASS("Car is deprecated") Car {}
```

I figured that maybe if I break comment into a few little macros maybe I could do it. And now, even if it shows correct expansion, it doesn't work because of "expected declaration"

Here is how I defined macro:
[image: Macro definition]

Here is the error and how it looks when expanded:
[image: Macro usage]

Also, here is one example before and after preprocessor:
[image: Example]
Edit1: It shows red '*/' in example macro, but fixing it doesn't make difference

Edit2: Here is code

```
#define D0(msg) \deprecated msg
#define D1(msg) * D0(msg)*
#define D2(msg) /D1(msg)/

#define DEPRECATED_CLASS(msg) D2(msg) class [[deprecated(msg)]]


DEPRECATED_CLASS("Consider using Ante") Mate
{
   public:
      int a = 0;
   private:
}
```

Comment: Please, never share code as images: we cannot copy/paste them, on some networks images are blocked, ... See [ask].

Comment: Comments are removed from translation before the preprocessor runs.

Comment: You'll need to write a custom preprocessor, since the preprocessor that comes with C++ cannot do that.  (Not as outlandish as it may sound.  One project I was on, we used our own preprocessor that was written in Python.  I've also heard of projects using the **m4** preprocessor as an alternative.  One may also consider **IDL** to be a form of a preprocessor, since preprocessor and a code generator are much alike.)

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to use a macro to insert a comment when comments are not preserved when compiling to object code.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

Comments are "removed" before the preprocessor run.

See [translation phases #3 and #4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases):

> #### Phase 3
>
> [...]
> 3 ) Each comment is replaced by one space character.
>
> #### Phase 4
>
> 1 ) The preprocessor is executed.

Maybe a tool to generate code would be your best solution.